# Form to a Panel vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
frmPatientManagement.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
frmPatientManagement.TopLevel = False

Me.MetroPanel1.Controls.Add(frmPatientManagement)
frmPatientManagement.Show()
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Only top-level controls can have an owner.

What to do?

Comment: Why do you need to put a form in a panel - they are both container controls?

Comment: how can I show a form to a panel? is it possible?

Comment: Not for nothing, but all of your past questions are rated 0 or less.  It is probably time to read [Ask] and take the [Tour] and perhaps visit the [help].  That many bad questions should put you on the brink of a throttle or ban.

Comment: I would not set the dock property

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible directly.

To get around this, you need to convert the Form by hand to a custom control.

This gives you what is effectively a panel that you can put into other forms. When you want to actually use it as a full form, you create a form to host it, put it in the form with the DockStyle like in your question.

Comment: I don't get it... I've been able to add a form to a panel before, though it's `Owner` property was Null.